# JavaScript Generated graph into a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a graph using Javascript. I would like that each chart/graph to be located between specific divs.

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<p>some text can go here or images ect</p>
<div id="chart2"></div>
```

This is so I can apply the CSS to it and move them around the page and add heading ext to each one. Currently, the code just generated the graphs under the Divs. My knowledge of Javascript is very basic and its the last part of the puzzle for this work.

[image]

Would anyone be able to help?

The main code for creating the two graphs is:

```
var chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.body, {
    width: 400,
    height: 175,
    layout: {
        textColor: '#d1d4dc',
        backgroundColor: '#000000',
    },
    localization: {
        priceFormatter: formatters[formatterNames[0]],
    },
    priceScale: {
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
    },
    timeScale: {
    visible: false,
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
    },
    priceScale: {
        scaleMargins: {
            top: 0.3,
            bottom: 0.25,
        },
    },
    grid: {
        vertLines: {
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
        },
        horzLines: {
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
        },
    },
});
```

And:

```
var chart2 = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.body, {
  width: 400,
  height: 175,
    layout: {
        textColor: '#d1d4dc',
        backgroundColor: '#000000',
    },
    localization: {
        priceFormatter: formatters[formatterNames[0]],
    },
    priceScale: {
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
    },
    timeScale: {
        visible: false,
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
    },
    priceScale: {
        scaleMargins: {
            top: 0.3,
            bottom: 0.25,
        },
    },
    grid: {
        vertLines: {
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
        },
        horzLines: {
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
        },
    },
});
```

I have added the full code to generate the graphs and HTML here: 
https://codepen.io/jarratt-perkins/pen/KKpqpPb

Comment: Look into using a canvas for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the container element where the chart should be created, when you call `LightweightCharts.createChart`. It is its first argument.

So change:

```
var chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.body, {
```

to:

```
var chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
```

And change:

```
var chart2 = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.body, {
```

to:

```
var chart2 = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.getElementById("chart2"), {
```

Comment: Thanks, trincot! That was alot simpler than I was thinking.